# Garage Fire Wall

Tags: drywall, garage

I'm in the process of selling my home and the Home Inspector has said the follow:

`The fire rating is compromised due to missing drywall at the access opening to the area under the front entry (wood is present)`

My house is a split-level home and there is a crawlspace that has an opening in the garage.  The 'door' is plywood.  Do I simply need to attach drywall to the plywood to resolve this?  Should there not be any access to the crawlspace from the garage?  Should I just remove the opening and make it a wall?

Answer (score 6):

The minimum fire code for connected garage spaces common to a living area is the rating of 5/8" drywall, or 1 hour. If you have a crawl space from the garage, you will need to seal it with a fire rated door of the same time rating or cover the hole with F/R sheetrock. This also applies to any vents, though piping, common wall windows, doors etc.

Comment: Thanks for the post.  I just want to make sure I understand; if I put 5/8" drywall over the plywood (in such a way that there is still an opening/you can access the crawl space) - would that do it?  Or are you saying I could install 5/8" drywall - removing the opening completely?

Comment: you would have to cover the edges of the plywood also or make a hatch that is very tight with the drywall.  There cannot be an air passage for fire to get through.  But you can do that.

Comment: you would have to cover the edges of the plywood also or make a hatch that is very tight with the drywall.  There cannot be an air passage for fire to get through.  I wound put up a solid, but removable 5/8' sheetrock panel over the opening to the crawl space. Then it is not unaccessible, but will meet fire codes.

Comment: sorry for the duplication, has some edit problems